# Java servlet is returning a blank page in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I recently tried to make a simple login page using Tomcat and mySQL, but everytime I ran the code, one of two the servlets kept on returning blank page. Here is the code for the servlets. The first one is from the login servlet and was the one that kept on returning blanks:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class login extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try{
            if(request.getParameter("username").isEmpty() || request.getParameter("pw").isEmpty()){
                out.println("<html>\n" +
                "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<a href = '/loginpage/'>Please fill in everything before you proceed</a>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>");
            }else{
                if(request.getParameter("username").length() < 50 && request.getParameter("pw").length() < 50){
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users", "javascrub", "xxxx");
                    statement = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from userTable where username = " + "'" + request.getParameter("username") + "'");
                    if(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()){
                        out.println("<html>\n" +
                        "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                        "<body>\n" +
                        "<a href = '/loginpage/'>Username does not exist, click to go back to login page</a><br>\n" +
                        "<a href = '/loginpage/signup.html'>Or click here to sign up</a>\n" +
                        "</body>\n" +
                        "</html>");
                    }else{
                        String pwCheck = null;
                        while(resultSet.next()){
                            pwCheck = resultSet.getString("password");
                        }
                        if(pwCheck.equals(request.getParameter("pw"))){
                            out.println("<html>\n" +
                            "<head><title>HomePage</title></head>\n" +
                            "<body>\n" +
                            "Congratulations " + request.getParameter("username") + ", you're logged in<br>\n" +
                            "<a href = '/loginpage/'>Log Out</a>\n" +
                            "</body>\n" +
                            "</html>");
                        }else{
                            out.println("<html>\n" +
                            "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                            "<body>\n" +
                            "<a href = '/loginpage/'>Incorrect password, click to go back</a>\n" +
                            "</body>\n" +
                            "</html>"); 
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    out.println("<html>\n" +
                    "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<a href = '/loginpage/'>Invalid username or password</a>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>");
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            out.println("<html>\n" +
            "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "<a href = '/loginpage/'>In finally block</a>\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>"); 
            out.close();
            try{
                if(statement != null){
                    statement.close();
                }
                if(conn != null){
                    conn.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second one is the signup servlet. Whenever I put this into the /classes folder and compile it, the login servlet returns blanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class signup extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest requestsu, HttpServletResponse responsesu) throws ServletException, IOException{
        responsesu.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter outsu = responsesu.getWriter();
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement stmnt = null;
        try{
            if(requestsu.getParameter("usernamesu").isEmpty() || requestsu.getParameter("pwsu").isEmpty()){
                outsu.println("<html>\n" +
                "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<a href = '/loginpage/signup.html'>Please fill in everything before you proceed</a>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>");
            }else{
                if(requestsu.getParameter("usernamesu").length() < 50 && requestsu.getParameter("pwsu").length() < 50){
                    String pw = null;
                    pw = requestsu.getParameter("pwsu");
                    char[] pwArray = pw.toCharArray();
                    int letterCount = 0;
                    int numCount = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < pwArray.length; i++){
                        if(Character.isLetter(pwArray[i])){
                            letterCount++;
                        }else{
                            numCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (numCount >= 2 && letterCount >= 3){
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users", "javascrub", "xxxx");
                        stmnt = connection.createStatement();
                        ResultSet resultSet = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from userTable where username = " + "'" + requestsu.getParameter("usernamesu") + "'");
                        if(resultSet.isBeforeFirst()){
                            outsu.println("<html>\n" +
                            "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                            "<body>\n" +
                            "<a href = '/loginpage/signup.html'>We are sorry, this usernname is already taken</a>\n" +
                            "</body>\n" +
                            "</html>");
                        }else{
                            int countInserted = stmnt.executeUpdate("insert into userTable values ('" + requestsu.getParameter("usernamesu") + "', '" + requestsu.getParameter("pwsu") + "')");
                            outsu.println("<html>\n" +
                            "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                            "<body>\n" +
                            "<a href = '/loginpage/'>Congratulations, your account has been created, click to go back to the login page\n" +
                            "</body>\n" +
                            "</html>");
                        }

                    }else{
                        outsu.println("<html>\n" +
                        "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                        "<body>\n" +
                        "<a href = '/loginpage/signup.html'>Your password did not fulfull all the requirements, please try again</a>\n" +
                        "</body>\n" +
                        "</html>");
                    }
                }else{
                    outsu.println("<html>\n" +
                    "<head><title>Error</title></head>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<a href = '/loginpage/signup'>Username and/or password too long</a>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>");
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            outsu.close();
            try{
                if(stmnt != null){
                    stmnt.close();
                }
                if(connection != null){
                    connection.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This servlet works completely fine, regardless of the login servlet being in the classes folder. I think this servlet might be interfering with the login servlet but I am not sure how. There might a problem with the Web-xml file so I will post it here but I don't think it is the source of the problem.

Here it is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app version="3.0"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

       <servlet>
          <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>login</servlet-class>
          <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>signup</servlet-class>
       </servlet>

       <!-- Note: All <servlet> elements MUST be grouped together and
             placed IN FRONT of the <servlet-mapping> elements -->

       <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
          <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/signuppage</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

I am just starting to learn web development and I really don't know much, so any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks!

*I can also put up the html pages if that would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>login</servlet-class>
      <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>signup</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
```

That makes no sense. You need two `<servlet>` element: one for each servlet.

Same for `<servlet-mapping>`.

Not sure why you're still using XML, instead of simply annotating your classes with `@WebServlet`.